# phonegap Html 5 application - android javascript libraries are loaded only in first index.html page

Tags: html, cordova

I am trying to create a phonegap HTML5, jQuery mobile app.
Everything is ok in the first index.html page.
When the user clicks to an internal link ex test.html,
the libraries are not loaded (ie I can't run their functions) unless
I add their code and declarations **inline**  in the first index.html page!

I am really stack, it doent make any sence!
Ondeviceready function doesn't fire at all.

If I run the page from pc's google chrome, the js code runs normally!

Have got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was sooo wrong.

I did not realize that phonegap uses ajax to load different pages. 
All javascript from pages other than the initial one (index.html) is stripped off.
Basically, you load all the js code in the index.html (in the js libraries included).

If anyone makes the same mistake as I did. This is the answer.